# Page width exceeds device width on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have [this website](http://www.contemporando.com.br) and it works great, except that when a mobile or tablet loads it, the page exceeds the normal device width size. I want it to be scaled exactly in 1.0 proportion, so the user doesn't have to zoom in or out to view the content sharply, and also doesn't have to move left or right to view the entire page.

I have looked for divs or any other content exceeding the device size, but could not find it. The viewport is set like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
```

And the body in CSS is like this:

```
body{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Where am I missing guys?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could put this in the body css with a combination of a mediaquery for the tablet/smartphone: overflow-x:hidden;

```
@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x:hidden !important;
  }
}
```

Change the values of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just telling the `body` to be `100% width` isn't going to handle your situation if you have something more specific in your CSS. For example, in your footer you have this button with the text " Assine nossa newsletter ". Look at the code and you'll see you have defined that div:

```
@media (max-width: 700px)
.newsletter .red {
width: 360px;
height: 70px;
}
```

It's more specific so your CSS for `body` is being overwritten. Try playing around in inspector and catching all the areas that need tweaking in mobile. It doesn't seem to be too much and the site is looking great!